# fusionauth /oauth2/token Error : invalid_redirect_uri

Tags: php, token, fusionauth

I'm trying to retrieve a OAUTH2 token from our fusionauth server 1.16.1
Login over SAML work's perfect. the login page php request /oauth2/authorize? and the redirect to /callback works.

login page php

```
    $redirect_url = urlencode('http://test.eyecatcher.ch/callback');
    $location = 'https://{auth domain}/oauth2/authorize?client_id={client id}&response_type=code&redirect_uri=' . $redirect_url;
    header( "Location: " . $location );
```

In fusionauth, OAuth Application-Settings, the "Authorized redirect URLs" are set.
It doesn't matter which redirect_url is entered, the error always appears

callback page php

```
    $client_id      = "{client id}";
    $clientSecret   = '{client secrect}';
    $base64Auth     = base64_encode($client_id . ":" . $clientSecret );

    $code           = $_GET[ "code" ];
    $url            = 'https://{auth domain}/oauth2/token';
    $redirect_url   = urlencode('http://test.eyecatcher.ch/callback');

    $header = array(    'Authorization: Basic ' .$base64Auth .'', 
                        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' );

    $post = [
        'code' => $code,
        'grant_type'   => 'authorization_code',
        'redirect_uri'   => $redirect_url,
        ];


    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    var_export($response);
```

After this request i get this error message.

```
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"redirect_uri: http%3A%2F%2Ftest.eyecatcher.ch%2Fcallback is not valid.","error_reason":"invalid_redirect_uri"}
```

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't look to be an issue with FusionAuth.

The PHP function `http_build_query` will URL encode the request body on your behalf.

Because you are pre-encoding the `redirect_url` using `urlencode` my guess is that the value of the `redirect_uri` which is now double encoded does not match your configured, authorized redirect URL once FusionAuth decodes the value.

Here is an example of building a POST body using only `http_build_query`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5676572/3892636

Comment: The urlencode was the problem, thank you for yor help!